# center an image when resizing an image and before imagefill

Tags: php

I'm new to php, actually new to everything in general. How do i center an image before imagefill? Right now the image goes to the left if the ratio is smaller than the new ratio and everything on the right is filled in white.

I've tried `imagecopyresampled($tn, $img_source, 0, 0, -$new_width/2, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);` well that just cuts everything in half of what the position is.

```
    if ( $image_ratio <= $mod_ratio ){
                $new_height = $mod_height;
                $new_width = $width / ($height / $mod_height);
            }
            else {
                $new_width = $mod_width;
                $new_height = $height / ($width / $mod_width);
            }

//blah blah         
            $tn= imagecreatetruecolor($mod_width, $mod_height);
            $whiteBackground = imagecolorallocate($tn, 255, 255, 255);
            imagefill($tn,0,0,$whiteBackground); 
            imagecopyresampled($tn, $img_source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
```